# CoreBluetooth Functions not working from Singleton

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

So I currently got a bluetooth connection setup between a iPad and iPhone. I've created my testcode in the `ViewController` and everything works fine. Now I moved it to 2 manager classes one for the `CBCentralManager` and one for the `CBPeripheralManager` above those to classes I made a `BluetoothManager` which is a singleton class and holds some information regarding currently connected devices.

However when doing this I'm facing a problem it seems like the `centralManager.connect()` call doesn't actually work. I debugged my entire code and after that line nothing seems to happen and I can't seem to figure out why this is or where I'm actually going wrong.

**The CentralManager class**

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class CentralManager: NSObject {
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []

    override init() {
        super.init()

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    }
}

// MARK: - CBCentralManager Delegate Methods
extension CentralManager: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [BLEConstants.serviceUUID], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if !peripherals.contains(peripheral) {
            peripheral.delegate = self
            peripherals.append(peripheral)
            centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.discoverServices([BLEConstants.serviceUUID])
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        guard let peripheralIndex = peripherals.index(of: peripheral), BluetoothManager.shared.deviceCharacteristic[peripheral] != nil else { return }

        peripherals.remove(at: peripheralIndex)
        BluetoothManager.shared.deviceCharacteristic.removeValue(forKey: peripheral)
    }

}

// MARK: - CBPeripheral Delegate Methods
extension CentralManager: CBPeripheralDelegate {

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        for service in peripheral.services! {
            if service.uuid == BLEConstants.serviceUUID {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
            let characteristic = characteristic as CBCharacteristic

            if BluetoothManager.shared.deviceCharacteristic[peripheral] == nil {
                BluetoothManager.shared.deviceCharacteristic[peripheral] = characteristic
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didModifyServices invalidatedServices: [CBService]) {

    }

}
```

**The PeripheralManager class**

```
class PeripheralManager: NSObject {
    private var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

}

// MARK: - Manage Methods
extension PeripheralManager {

    func updateAdvertising() {
        guard !peripheralManager.isAdvertising else { peripheralManager.stopAdvertising(); return }

        let advertisingData: [String: Any] = [CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: BLEConstants.serviceUUID,
                               CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: BLEConstants.bleAdvertisementKey]
        peripheralManager.startAdvertising(advertisingData)
    }

    func initializeService() {
        let service = CBMutableService(type: BLEConstants.serviceUUID, primary: true)

        let characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: BLEConstants.charUUID, properties: BLEConstants.charProperties, value: nil, permissions: BLEConstants.charPermissions)
        service.characteristics = [characteristic]

        peripheralManager.add(service)
    }

}

// MARK: - CBPeripheralManager Delegate Methods
extension PeripheralManager: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
            initializeService()
            updateAdvertising()
        }
    }

    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]) {
        for request in requests {
            if let value = request.value {
                let messageText = String(data: value, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print(messageText ?? "")
            }
            self.peripheralManager.respond(to: request, withResult: .success)
        }
    }

}
```

**The BluetoothManager class**

```
class BluetoothManager {
    static let shared = BluetoothManager()
    private var centralManager: CentralManager!
    private var peripheralManager: PeripheralManager!

    var deviceCharacteristic: [CBPeripheral: CBCharacteristic] = [:]
    var connectedPeripherals: [CBPeripheral] { return centralManager.peripherals }

    func setup() {
        centralManager = CentralManager()
        peripheralManager = PeripheralManager()
    }

}
```

and then in my `ViewController didLoad` I'm calling `BluetoothManager.shared.setup()`

Does anyone know why the devices don't seem to connect with eachother or maybe the delegate functions after that just don't get called?

Comment: This might just be a wild-guess, but objects are instantiated with the 'init' method in Swift, not with 'setup'. Are you sure that your BluetoothManager is initialized correctly?

Comment: @fishinear true but I'm calling the setup function in the `ViewController` when the `didLoad` is called so I'm basically creating my own init function for it since the singleton instantiates itself and I have no control over when this happens. I did the setup way because in the regular init none of the delegate functions where being called

Answer (score 0):

The process starts when the static `shared` variable is initialized with `BluetoothManager()`. I am not sure when this happens in Swift, it is either at the very start of the program, or when you use `BluetoothManager.setup` for the first time. 
Initialization of the variable calls the `init()` method of the `BluetoothManager`. This will instantiate a `CentralManager`, and its `init()` method will be called. This will instantiate a `CBCentralManager`, which will start the Bluetooth process.

Then you call `setup()`, which will instantiate a new `CentralManager`, with its own `CBCentralManager`. I can imagine something goes wrong with two `CBCentralManager`.

To solve it, don't use `setup()`, but initialize the variables in `init()` instead.

To debug this kind of situation, put breakpoints in all `init()` methods. Create destructors, and put breakpoints in those as well. Technically, you need destructors anyways, because you need to remove yourself as delegate from the `CBCentralManager` object.

---

Note also that you only call `scanForPeripherals` from `centralManagerDidUpdateState`. The `CBCentralManager` can already be in `poweredOn` state when it starts, this can happen when another app is using Bluetooth at the same time - or when your first `CBCentralManager` object has already started it. In that case, `centralManagerDidUpdateState` will never be called.

Comment: I just created the setup to have control over when the managers are being setup. However I did find out the problem when setting up the `startAdvertising` I passed the `ServiceUUID` as a object instead of as an array of `UUID's` this is why it wasn't working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Singleton is correctly initialized?

Try this:

```
import Foundation

private let singleton = Singleton()

class Singleton {

  static let sharedInstance : Singleton = {
    return singleton
  }()

  let cnetralManager = = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
}
```