# Bluetooth Peripheral detect connected state

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I created a function which turns an iPad without gps chip into a bluetooth peripheral and any device (iPhone or iPad) with gps chip into a broadcaster.

These 2 devices then connect with each other without asking to pair (as intended). (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771422/corebluetooth-functions-not-working-from-singleton) post for the code I wrote)

However I want to show the connected state in both the peripheral and broadcaster. The broadcaster has a function to check the connection state. The peripheral doesn't seem to have this.

Does anyone know of a way to determine at the peripheral side if the connection is still connected or not.

Comment: I suspect that you probably have your roles the wrong way around. The GPS device should be the peripheral and the non-GPS device should be the central role. The non-GPS device can then subscribe to updates on the location characteristic and your peripheral can send a new location to the subscribed centrals when a location update is received. But the answer to your question is that the `CBPeripheralManager` doesn't expose any methods that provide the currently connected centrals. If you swap roles as I suggest, then you can track the number of subscribed centrals.

Comment: @Paulw11 I could change them around like you suggest (are there any other benefits other then moving the location of tracking the connected devices). The issue is I want to show this message of the connected/disconnected state on both the peripheral and central

Comment: The main benefit I see is that it is the device with the GPS that knows when it has a new location. It is more efficient for it to publish to observers than for the devices without GPS to have to continually poll for an updated location. By tracking the number of subscribers you know how many are connected

Comment: @Paulw11 alright I can see where you are coming from. Not entirely sure yet how I would write data from the peripheral to the central, if you have an example that would be great.

However the fact remains that in this case the GPS device (iPhone) is unable to determine if the central is disconnected, so there is no way to display a "bluetooth disconnected" message on both devices

Comment: You have your central subscribe to the characteristic on the peripheral. When you have new data (location) your peripheral just notifies all of the subscribed centrals. When a central disconnects you will get a delegate callback telling you that it unsubscribed. If the subscriber count is 0, no centrals are connected. If it is > 0 then something is connected.